# Delete doesn't work in backend

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have 3 buttons in my indexSuccess in the backend of my project. The show and edit buttons work fine but the delete goes to show.
I think the code is right, here it is:

```
  <div class="cont2">
        <a href="<?php echo url_for('marcacao/delete?id='.$feasy_marcacao->getId()); ?>">
          <div class="btapagar"/>
            <p class="btapagartxt">
              Apagar
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. This `<a href="<?php echo url_for('marcacao/delete?id='.$feasy_marcacao->getId()); ?>">` is wrong. It should be:        `<a href="<?php echo 'marcacao/'.$feasy_marcacao->getId().'/delete' ?>" >`
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Check your log for the app you are running - you can see what happens which this link is clicked - you need to check the correct route is being followed - then check the controller to see what you are doing for that routes action.

Comment: so in log it says that its going to 'show'. in the `action.class.php` i have this 
`public function executeDelete(sfWebRequest $request)
  {

    $this->forward404Unless($feasy_marcacao = Doctrine_Core::getTable('FeasyMarcacao')->find(array($request->getParameter('id'))), sprintf('Object feasy_marcacao does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));
    $feasy_marcacao->delete();

    $this->redirect('marcacao/index');
  }`
can you tell if there's something wrong? thank you

Comment: The problem is not with the method - the `executeDelete` method is not even being run - the log says its following the 'show' route - that means its executing `executeShow` method in the `actions.class.php`

Comment: Add your routing.yml to your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think re-creating the URLs by hand is the best practice, you should be using url_for() or link_to().
I had the same problem with a project on symfony 1.2 (Propel) using the admin generator : all the links worked fine except for delete, so I added a route in routing.yml like that :

```
marcacao_delete:
  url:   /marcacao/:id/delete
  param: { module: marcacao, action: delete }
```

and that solved the problem